# UWP NavigationView multiple pages of same type

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I allow the user to add additional navigation items to the navigation pane. All of these have the same page type (`SCWebViewPage`). The problem is that when navigating, you only provide the type not the instance. Obviously, i could make use of the object param to specify which view should be loaded. However i would then not be able make use of navigation cache. Any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: The question is that you are not able to use NavigationCacheMode? As it doesn't store (cache) although same page type but with different content on it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UWP's `Frame` allows only navigation to page type using `Navigate(Type pageType, object parameter)` method. This means new navigation **always** creates new instance of the page. You cannot navigate to an existing instance (although it is possible to *assign* a page instance to `Frame.Content` but that is not the correct approach and goes against the whole purpose of the `Frame`).

What you can do is to provide a `parameter` which will be used by the page to know what should be displayed. I think what confused you is that many samples use a tag parameter on the menu items to define which page type should be navigated to, but you can just as easily use an arbitrary string which you can then utilize to know where you would like to navigate for example. See this [blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/05/06/using-the-navigationview-in-your-uwp-applications/) for a similar approach. As an example see this:

```
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Tag="FirstPage">
   <TextBlock>First</TextBlock>
</NavigationViewItem>
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Setting" Tag="SecondPage">
   <TextBlock>Second</TextBlock>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

Now in the code handling the item selection:

```
private void nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, 
                                       NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
     var item = args.InvokedItemContainer;
     if (item != null)
     {
           switch (item.Tag)
           {
               case "FirstPage":
                  contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SCWebViewPage), "someParam");
               break;

               case "SecondPage":
                  contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SCWebViewPage), "differentParam");
               break;
           }
     }
}
```

Now in the `SCWebViewPage` code you can override `OnNavigatedTo` method, check the `parameter` and act accordingly:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter == "someParameter") ...
    else ...
}
```

As long as the navigation parameter is a seralizable type (which `string` definitely is), this will in no way affect the functionality of your app and you can even fully store and reload the `Frame` navigation state on suspension/restore.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks. Yep - that is in fact what i ended up doing. The original problem was that i wanted to be able to cache both, so the user wouldn't have to wait for the pages to load everytime. What i ended up doing was creating my own cache hack. On navigating from the page, i take a bitmap image of the screen, and on navigating back, i display the bitmap while the content loads. A nasty hack to say the least, but it satisfies my requirements

Comment: In case you have the data in a ViewModel that is persisted, data binding to an existing view model from a new page should be pretty much immediate as well. You can check out how MVVM pattern usually handles this - for example in MvvmCross or Prism libraries

Comment: Old post, but to clarify, it's not quite accurate to say that a navigation ALWAYS creates a new page instance. It will only create a new instance (that is, run the constructor) if the `NavigationCacheMode` is either `Disabled`, or if it's `Enabled` and the cache limit is hit. It will not run again if set to `Required`, but in all cases you'll still get the `OnNavigatedTo` with the new navigation parameter.